# FCM 15.0.2 cannot make token in release build with Dexguard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, dexguard

I'm Using FCM with Dexguard.
FCM cannot make token in release build.
but, it works well in debug build.

my gradle settings

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

And, `ShrinkResources = false` And optimize 5time by Dexguard

`gradle version : 4.1`
`android gradle plugin : 2.3.3`

options in dexguardFile related with FCM

```
-keep public class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId { public *;}
```

Comment: You could try the latest versions of the plugins: [com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) and [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-1-0).

Comment: okay, I'll try it

Comment: @KyeongraeCho: Did you fix the problem? I have exactly the same problem. The Method onTokenRefresh() of FirebaseInstanceIdService will not get called in release version with dexguard, only in debug version. All Libraries up to date.

Comment: @user2082415 I cannot fix it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase 15+ requires some additional rules. The latest DexGuard version 8.2.09 for example includes all necessary configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dexguard rules to fix the problem:

```
-keep class com.google.firebase** { *; }
-dontshrink
```

It seems that dexguard removes all classes that are not directly referenced in code. So the entry points like services classes to get firebase tokens (FirebaseInstanceIdService) will be removed during obfuscation process, if shrinking is allowed.

Comment: I am using firebase since the first of project with dexguard. Only 15.x firebase makes problem

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Firebase analytics where it works for debug build but not the release build, thanks to T. Neidhart's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51500521/4246595) above I found this block from the Dexguard 8.4.13 sample - *samples/advanced/GooglePlayServices/AdMob/dexguard-project.txt* and it solves the problem for me.

```
-keep public class !**.internal.**, com.google.** {
    public protected *;
}
# We can repackage all obfuscated classes in a new internal package.
-repackageclasses com.google.internal
```